# PanGestureHandler (from 'react-native-gesture-handler') not launching event

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I am trying to use the PanGestureHandler component (from 'react-native-gesture-handler') like this: (Very simple exemple, just a console.log("test") when a touch is detected)

```
import React from 'react';
import { View,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {PanGestureHandler} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'


export default class App extends React.Component {
  test = ()=>{
    console.log("test")
  }

render(){
  return(
    <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={this.test}>
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>

      </View>  
    </PanGestureHandler>
  )
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 mainContainer: {
   backgroundColor: 'red',
   height: 200,
   width: 200,
 },
});
```

But nothing apears in the debug stream.
This is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "gesturetest",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
  "android": "react-native run-android",
  "ios": "react-native run-ios",
  "start": "react-native start",
  "test": "jest",
  "lint": "eslint ."
},
"dependencies": {
  "react": "17.0.1",
  "react-native": "0.64.2",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
  "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.6",
  "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
  "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
  "eslint": "^7.30.0",
  "jest": "^27.0.6",
  "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
  "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.1",
  "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
},
"jest": {
  "preset": "react-native"
 }
}
```